# SCons long command line TEMPFILE with MinGW

Tags: python, mingw, scons

I'm trying to build a shared library from gcc and gfortran objects using SCons and MinGW on Windows, but during the final link the command line is too long, in excess of 18000 characters.  I know I need to use a tempfile (response file?) to pass the command line, but I can't find a way to get SCons to do this directly.  I was using CMake for this library and it handled the response file without my interference.

SCons appears to be using the CommandGeneratorAction to generate the shared library command line.  Is there a way to tell this action to use the response file mechanism?  Is there another method for handling long command lines that I'm overlooking?

Relevant SConscript:

```
sqllib = env.SharedLibrary(target='fvssql', source=sqllib_sources, LIBS=['odbc32',])
ffelib = env.SharedLibrary(target='fvspncffe', source=ffelib_sources, LIBS=[sqllib,], LIBPATH=['.',])

fvsobjs = env.SharedObject(fvslib_sources)
fvsobjs = [obj for obj in fvsobjs if obj.get_suffix()=='.o']

fvslib = env.SharedLibrary(target='fvspnc', source=fvsobjs, LIBS=sqllib+ffelib, LIBPATH=['.',])
```

Relevant output from env.Dump():

```
'SHLIBSUFFIX': '.dll',
'SHLINK': '$LINK',
'SHLINKCOM': <SCons.Action.CommandGeneratorAction object at 0x02DDF770>,
'SHLINKFLAGS': ['$LINKFLAGS', '-shared'],
```

I could prepare the command line template in my environment `env['SHLINKCOM']="${TEMPFILE('$SHLINK -o $TARGET ... $SOURCE')}"`, but this seems fragile and I'd prefer to let SCons handle it if possible.

I tried using string substitution `env['SHLINKCOM']='${TEMPFILE("%s")}' % (env['SHLINKCOM'],)`, but the result was an incomplete command line and now response file anyhow.

**EDIT**

I have seen the [LongCmdLinesOnWin32](http://scons.org/wiki/LongCmdLinesOnWin32) workaround.  I would prefer to use the TEMPFILE, TempFileMunge, commandline indirection mechanism if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen http://scons.org/wiki/LongCmdLinesOnWin32? It looks like there is an answer to your exact problem with long command ling during the link phase.

Comment: I have seen this workaround. However, this [solution](http://scons.org/wiki/LongCmdLinesOnWin32?action=recall&rev=1) is now 8 years old. It seems SCons has evolved to use the tempfile indirection mechanism since then. If I can't pin down the appropriate use of tempfile then I'll give this workaround a try.

Comment: The last comment is pretty recent. Anyway, if you'll find a better way, a patch is always appreciated. http://scons.org/wiki/LongCmdLinesOnWin32?action=diff&rev1=40&rev2=41

Comment: Note there are issues with [LongCmdLinesOnWin32](http://scons.org/wiki/LongCmdLinesOnWin32).  It needs to be extended to handle path names with embedded quotes (added to handle spaces in a cygwin environment) but futhermore, there appears to be some problem with visual studio.  It looks as if the VS environment installs it's own version of SPAWN, which starts up the MSVC command line shell (thus setting the needed env. values), causing compiles using 'cl' to fail.