# Link command line too long: how to use response files when linking in scons on windows

Tags: windows, linker, scons, googletest

Like [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357425/scons-long-command-line-tempfile-with-mingw) I have a link line that exceeds the Windows cmd line limit.  For most cases we have solved the problem by building intermediate archives (aka static libraries) with subsets of the object files and performed the final link with those archives.  However using this strategy with Google Test this causes the tests not to be found, specifically the tests defined in the object files that were archived.

Update: [This is why](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/Primer#Important_note_for_Visual_C++_users).  I will probably use this workaround, but I would still like to understand how to make response files work under scons.

The  [LongCmdLinesOnWin32](http://scons.org/wiki/LongCmdLinesOnWin32) fix is problematic.  We have a cygwin environment and pathnames that include spaces, so some compiler absolute paths involve quotes.  The script in LongCmdLinesOnWin32 first needs to be extended to handle both the embedded quotes and the spaces (otherwise it creates separate tokens of a single path name).  More seriously, when using MS Visual Studio, the compiler command is just 'cl' i.e doesn't include the pathname.  This is not available in the PATH environment--it appears to be dynamically set (somehow) and not visible when constructing the cmdline argument to the LongCmdLinesOnWin32 script.  But I digress....

There seems to be a much simpler (and to my eyes suitable) solution: [response files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404301.aspx), which are also [supported by gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Response_Files).

I wrote a little function to take the list of object names and print them to a text file, one to a line, something like:

```
"""
  In place for generating response files
"""
def gen_response_file(filename,file_list):
    with open(filename,"w") as f:
        for obj_name in file_list:
            f.write ('%s\n' %os.path.abspath(str(obj_name)).replace('\\','/'))
    return filename
```

I then tried prepending the '@' character to the file name and added it to the list of options.

The command line echoed was:

```
link /nologo /MACHINE:x86 /DEBUG @E:\dev\pcoip_view_client\soft_test.rsp /OUT:blah_client\blah_client_tests.exe /LIBPATH:\\sterbkp03\qt\4.8.2\lib ....
```

If I simply named the file "soft_test" then scons would add the suffix ".obj" and the linker could not find it, so I tried adding the suffix '.rsp'.  Now, the linker complains it cannot find the file, but it is present.  I captured the output from scons and pasted it to a bat file.  When I ran the bat file (from the VS 2008 command line env.) the link worked like a charm, so it seems like scons is somehow causing the problem with finding the file

I tried changing the path, using absolute (@C:\blah\soft_test.rsp), relative (@.\soft_test.rsp) and just @soft_test.rsp, none of them worked.

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '@E:\dev\swift.dev\blah_client\soft_test.rsp'
scons: *** [blah_client\blah_client_tests.exe] Error 1104
```

I'm using scons v2.1.0.r5357, VS 2008 and python 2.7 under Windows 7-64

My scons file looks like:

```
test_objects = tenv.Object(test_sources)
xx = gen_response_file('soft_test.rsp',test_objects)
tenv.Append( LINKFLAGS = [ '@%s' % os.path.abspath(xx)]) # 
test_exe = tenv.Program(target = 'blah_client_tests', source = objects + moc_objects + qrc_objects )
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Update: I tried with gcc and there was no problem.  My guess is that somehow the scons rules associated with Visual Studio tools is different enough to cause grief.

Comment: Can you please provide the complete output from SCons.

Comment: Hmm, it's huge and I don't think it's much more informative than the snippet I gave above--just has a long list of object names.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce this in Linux using gcc, and came across a different problem, whose solution may help.

Originally, I used this SConscript:

```
import os

"""
  In place for generating response files
"""
def gen_response_file(filename,file_list):
    with open(filename,"w") as f:
        for obj_name in file_list:
            f.write ('%s\n' %os.path.abspath(str(obj_name)).replace('\\','/'))
    return filename

env = Environment()

test_objects = env.Object(target = 'testClass', source = 'testClass.cc')

resp_file = gen_response_file('response_file.rsp', test_objects)

env.Append(LINKFLAGS = [ '@%s' % os.path.abspath(resp_file)])
env.Program(target = 'helloWorld', source = 'helloWorld.cc')
```

Here are the related source files I used:

```
# tree .
.
|-- SConstruct
|-- helloWorld.cc
|-- testClass.cc
`-- testClass.h
```

Where `helloWorld.cc` is the main program. `helloWorld.cc` includes `testClass.h` and links in `testClass.o` When I tried to compile this, the response file was correctly generated (only contains `/some/path/testClass.o`) and read by the compiler. The problem that I came across was that `testClass.o` was not compiled, since SCons doesnt appear to recognize the dependency with the objects listed in the response file. Here is the result:

```
# scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o helloWorld.o -c helloWorld.cc
g++ -o helloWorld @/some/path/response_file.rsp helloWorld.o
g++: /some/path/testClass.o: No such file or directory
scons: *** [helloWorld] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

This seems like a failure in SCons because it doesnt analyze the response file. To solve this problem, I had to use the `Depends()` function as in the following excerpt:

```
...
bin = env.Program(target = 'helloWorld', source = 'helloWorld.cc')
env.Depends(bin, test_objects)
```

This worked and gave me the following:

```
# scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o helloWorld.o -c helloWorld.cc
g++ -o testClass.o -c testClass.cc
g++ -o helloWorld @/some/path/response_file.rsp helloWorld.o
scons: done building targets.
```

I know this doesnt answer the original question about why the response files cant be found, but once you solve that, you will most likely run into the problem mentioned above, and have to use the `Depends()` function.

Comment: Yes, I came across this problem as well, but solved it differently--sorry, should have mentioned it.  Instead of using source files as input to the response file, I first generated a list of objects (as in obj_list = env.Object(src_list).  The env.Object exposes the dependency to scons and ensures they are generated.

Comment: Interesting: gcc doesn't seem to have a problem.